# Ubuntu "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: ssh

I have been trying to figure out this problem for days. I used to have a samba server and ssh server up and running in Ubuntu that I could connect to from my raspberry pi. I am unable to connect to either from any device now. I am led to believe that the problem is with ubuntu and not the individual services as I get the same "Connection reset by peer" error message for both. here is a the output from my attempts to connect via ssh

```
OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u2, OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u2
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22
```

has anyone seen these error messages before and have any insight into how to resolve them? I have checked the /etc/ssh/ssh.allowed and deny files and ssh.deny was empty so I added my local IP for the pi for good measure. I have also tried reconfiguring ssh and un/reinstalling it both on Ubuntu and the pi to see if that works. ANy help is appreciated

Comment: You added your IP to ssh.deny? Do you have fail2ban running?

Comment: @OrganicMarble no sorry if that was unclear, I added it to ssh.allow to see if that would fix the problem. I do not have fail2ban installed on my machine.

Comment: I just tried it with -vvv; I don't have the "resolve_canonicalize..." line in my output; otherwise it is similar up to the "Local verson..." string line; then it's all different.

Answer (score 1):

This could have many reasons, e.g. network issues, firewall setting, etc.

Run `cat /var/log/kern.log | grep netfiler` to check if your server firewall blocks the connections.

You could try unblock the port with `sudo ufw allow 22/tcp` for SSH and `sudo ufw allow 445/tcp` for Samba.

If you're client and server are on different networks, it could also be firewall on a router in between or a DNS issue if you're using DNS names.

[This article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-fix-ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer-error) gives some more explanations.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I should have mentioned that I actually disabled my firewall for both the pi and ubuntu server for testing purposes and it did not change anything. Just to be sure I ran the ```cat /var/log/kern.log | grep netfiler``` command and get no output for either device. Both devices are on a wired connection to the same network. I will check out this article, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi was listed as DMZ on the router. Once that was delisted  everything worked as expected.